# How to develop magento with git?

Tags: php, mysql, git, magento, amazon-web-services

I want to use git to develop the `magento` website. The local development environment is `xampp` and the ultimate website should run in the `AWS`, which is a `lamp` environment.

I use a git tool called SourceTree to control the local source in the `xampp`. After the `xampp` site is working well, I push the local source to the `AWS server`. yes the source is the same as the local. but, the `mysql` data can't be synchronsized. (if I config something in the admin panel of `magento`, the `mysql` data will be changed. In this way, the server side `mysql` data will not change.)

I think there should be a `DB migration tool` to synchronize the Database. this is just a thinking of new, any professional `magento` developer point me the right way to organize the team development. Thanks so much!

Comment: You should not synchronize internal database files across different platforms.  Create a SQL dump and import it into a blank database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Code organisation - you should use branches when doing new development, then you can merge the branch to the master when you want the new changes to go the production environment. You can remove branches after merging, but this is your choice.

2) Database - take a backup of your database, upload it as part of your code if not too large, use FTP if too large, then, create an .sh script which would trigger a database import on AWS. You can execute the .sh script from AWS. You would need to know how to write a bash script. You could do direct commands from the server itself. If your production environment cannot experience downtime, I suggest you do backed changes manually, and everything else from SQL upgrade script.

3) Always use useful comments when updating branches / master. A identification system would make your life much easier. Ex, New Development #1, #2 and so on. You could even use a tool like 'targertprocess' which would allow you to keep a full history of what you are doing.

4) Git usually comes with a WIKI, use and update this WIKI to your advantage. Place deployment instructions here and so on.

5) It might not be possible, but try to keep similar environments in your process. So you should use a LAMPP based system if your production environment is based on LAMPP. Use a VM instead of XAMPP, checkout the tool 'vagrant' for this, and this website to create VMs easily. (https://puphpet.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are so kind! thanks so much! I love you!!! bbbb